# Generated test can't read property from application.yml

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

Just trying hands with Spring Cloud Contract. While running the generated test on provider side and when the application context is instantiated, it is unable to read config values from application.yml. When i move the test from generated build folder to src/test/java then issue is not seen anymore.
Which implies since build folder is outside of project src/.. structure, it can't read the config.
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

How do you access the value from application.yml
Let's suppose in application.yml you have the following content:

```
example:
  baseUri: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
```

You can simply access it in your test using:

```
@Value("${example.baseUri}")
String exampleBaseUri;
```

Additionally, if you want a profile just for tests you can create a file application-test.yml where you add properties. To access it values from this file you need to add before your test class:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
```

Comment: Thanks @adambogdan1993, i think you didn't talk about the issue where tests are not sitting under src/test/java folder. if you move test to a directory such as "projectroot/build" and try to read the values ...thats where i see the issue.